# How to update the class an elements id of which is provided available in another elements name whenever the other elements comes in focus

Tags: css, html

I have a textbox A which has the name as reqA. When i have focus in A then i want to change css of another element which has id as name of A which in this case is reqA using css/hml5 but not js.

Sorry for the messy language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, what you want to do isn't possible without JS. There maybe alternatives, if you show the HTML. BTW if you need to support older IEs, you should avoid having two different elements share the same id and name because IE didn't distinguish between the two and could get confused.

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually i dont have 2 elements with the same id. Textbox A has NAME as reqA where id of other element is reqA.

Comment: @Ranger I didn't express it well, but that's exactly the problematic scenario I meant: One element which has a name and different one which has an id, and the name and the id are the same. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/BUkYD/ . A proper browser will first alert `1` because there is one element with the name "ABC", and then alert `DIV`, because that's the element with the ID "ABC". However IE (even IE8, I'm not sure about IE9) will alert `2` and `INPUT`, because it considers `name` and `id` to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

id are unique you cant use same id for two elements in a page 1 id per html page this is all you can use class for this